# Unable To Write to a text box from a method

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Im currently trying to create a messaging application from client to server. When the server sends the client a message it will open up an new form and add the text to a text box inside the form.

However the client is defiantly reviving the message, I tested this with a message box displaying the message before trying to update the text box. The text box is displaying the message perfectly.

However, when i try to edit the textboxt nothing happens. However my other method on a button click works perfectly. really unsure why this is happening.

I've also written an invoke method to check if the textbox need's to be invoked as i am using differen't threads for some methods.

Below is an example of my code with some screenshots the method below is being opened from another form "MAIN" i have reference to it in the code. Not sure if that is causing an issue perhaps?

```
public ChatWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread timerThread = new Thread(Main.ReceiveLoop);
        timerThread.Start();
    }


    private void txtChatLog_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string clientReply = txtReply.Text;
        string Message = "ClientMsg§" + clientReply;
        var time = DateTime.Now;
        txtChatWindow.AppendText($"{time} client: {clientReply}");
        txtChatWindow.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        Main main = new Main();
        main.ChatResponse(Message);
        txtReply.Text = "";

    }

    delegate void setTextCallBack(string message);

    public void UpdateChatLog(string message)
    {
        if (txtChatWindow.InvokeRequired)
        {
            setTextCallBack d = new setTextCallBack(UpdateChatLog);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { message });
        }
        else
        {
            var time = DateTime.Now;
            string newMessage = message.Split('$')[1];
            string messageToDisplay = $"{time} Server: {newMessage}";
            MessageBox.Show(messageToDisplay);
            this.txtChatWindow.AppendText(messageToDisplay);
            this.txtChatWindow.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

        }
    }
```

Below are some images of my server and the code running on the client:
[image: Image of what is happening On screen]

as you can see the server is recieving what the client replies with, the textbox is also being appended for when the client presses the SEND button. However it isn't being changed when the method is called. You know the method is being called because the MessageBox.Show is being called and displaying what should be in the text box.

Really unsure what the issue is here. If anyone could help me It would be very appreciated! This is a project for my university degree that is due in soon!

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: `Main main = new Main();`?  You never show this form.  I suspect you don't want to actually create a *new* main here.

Comment: @LarsTech Im just trying to use methods from that form, That part works fine, that is the method to reply to the server. Its the UpdateChatLog method that isn't currently working.

Comment: I don't see any code that calls UpdateChatLog.

Comment: @LarsTech The code that is calling it is in the main form, it isn't important to see that code, you know that it is defiantly being called because the messagebox's are being shown on screen.